# Why a type cannot be constrained?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am struggling with the following code:

```
DECLARE
  TOTACID TAB_OF_ID(50);
  RES NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT ID INTO TOTACID
  FROM TABLE_B;

  FOR indx IN 1 .. TOTACID.COUNT
    LOOP
      RES := F_IMPORT(TOTACID(indx));
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Moved ID ' || RES);
    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

When I run it, it fails with the error:

> Error report -
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 11:
>   PLS-00566: type name "TAB_OF_ID" cannot be constrained
>   ORA-06550: line 5, column 19:
>   PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected UDT got NUMBER
>   ORA-06550: line 5, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Where `TAB_OF_ID` has been declared as follows:

```
create or replace TYPE TAB_OF_ID AS table of NUMBER(19,2);
```

I don't understand what is wrong. It seems that I cannot declare `TOTACID TAB_OF_ID(50)` but in a function I created some days ago I could declare `LIS_ID TAB_OF_ID := TAB_OF_ID(50);` and it works properly.
What is the difference with the script I have here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not declare the variable by assigning your table a fixed number of records, so you need something like:

```
DECLARE
  TOTACID TAB_OF_ID;
  RES NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT DISTINCT ID bulk collect INTO TOTACID
  FROM TABLE_B;
  ...
END;
/
```

Also, notice that you are fetching more than one value, so you need `BULK COLLECT INTO`.

About

`LIS_ID TAB_OF_ID := TAB_OF_ID(50);`

here you are not declaring a variable with a given number of records, but you are assigning to a variable the 50th value of the table.

Comment: You're right, I forgot the `BULK COLELCT` and I didn't know that during the declaration `:= {inital value}` can be omitted. This is so confused for the programmer. Thanks for helping. Solved.

Answer (score 3):

Obviously `TOTACID TAB_OF_ID(50)` is different to `LIS_ID TAB_OF_ID := TAB_OF_ID(50);`  The command is like

```
{variable name} {data type} := {inital value};
```

where `:= {inital value}` is optional.

`TOTACID TAB_OF_ID(50)` would mean

```
{variable name} {inital value};
```

which is not valid syntax.